# the page that I created opens and closes immediately

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget

I want to open a second window when the button is pressed. The window opens and closes immediately. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QApplication

class FirstWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('It\'s working!')
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        second_screen_btn = QPushButton('Open second screen', self)
        second_screen_btn.setGeometry(250, 100, 100, 100)
        second_screen_btn.clicked.connect(self.open_second_screen)
        self.show()

    def open_second_screen(self):
        second_window = SecondWindow()

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('This is a second window')
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = FirstWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi, please provides a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: change `second_window` to `self.second_window`

Comment: posible duplicate of [PyQt: Why does new window close immediately after opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247583)

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your `open_second_screen` to this:

```
def open_second_screen(self):
    self.second_window = SecondWindow()
    self.second_window.show()
```

(And remove the self.show() from the other class, of course)

This is a reccurent issue with PyQt. New windows are garbage collected if not stored in a variable, and the `second_window` variable is deleted when the function ends, unless you store it as a parameter of your window's instance.