# PyQt5 window opens then closes in a second

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.9

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("QPushButton")
        left = 300
        top = 200
        width = 300
        height = 250
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)
        self.show()


def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main()
    sys.exit(App.exec())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I don't get it, it worked before now it closes within a second of opening. I'm thinking somehow my installation got corrupted. Do you have any ideas I tried

```
def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main()
    App.exec_()
```

Comment: I should add theres no error output

Comment: The window will be garbage-collected if you don't keep a reference (just like any other python object). Do `main = Main()`.

Comment: that was it make that an answer and ill check it

Comment: It's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16069713/984421) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42247583/984421), so it should really be closed as a duplicate.